# Why is C++ code needed for opengl es on android?

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I am referring to the using of c++ code in strings in this official android training post. Why hasn't google eliminated all need for native languages inside it's ' java world '?

Link:http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/draw.html

Under "draw a shape".

Thanks in advance for satisfying my curiosity.

Also, this may be a stupid question, and if so, please say so kindly while still giving me an answer.

Comment: What you see on that page is GLSL shader code, not C++.

Comment: Yes, this is a stupid question

Answer (score 2):

The `GLES20` class provides you Java wrapper methods, so you are not really using C++ yourself. Under the hood, Android uses JNI to bind these Java wrapper methods to their corresponding C/C++ implementation.

If you are referring to the shaders, it is not C++ what is being used. OpenGL ES 2.0 provides more flexibility by allowing you to specify how the pipeline should draw each vertex and fragment. It does so by using the OpenGL Shading Language which is what is shown on the docs.

Answer (score -2):

Because C and C++ are at a minimum 30% faster than Java code, and often even better.  If you want high performance (and base 3d graphics libraries need high performance), you need to use C.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The original poster just completely misunderstood the linked page.

Comment: It absolutely answers his question.  He asked "Why hasn't google eliminated all need for native languages inside it's ' java world '? "  The answer is performance.

Comment: @GabeSechan ,check the link he posted,he misunderstood GLSL(shaders) for c++ code.